# Android Espresso Testing - Checking Buttons

Tags: android, android-testing, android-espresso

So I've written a basic test for my homescreen right now that checks if the three buttons on the homescreen are clickable. I was wondering how I would check to see if each of the buttons go to the right activity when they are clicked.

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
@SmallTest
public class HomeScreenTest {

@Rule
public ActivityTestRule<StartActivity> mActivityRule = new ActivityTestRule<>(StartActivity.class);

@Test
public void testButton() {

    Espresso.onView(withId(R.id.event_button)).check(matches(isClickable()));
    Espresso.onView(withId(R.id.navigation_button)).check(matches(isClickable()));
    Espresso.onView(withId(R.id.alarm_button)).check(matches(isClickable()));
                         }
                            }
```

Comment: Have you tried clicking it, and then asserting that the new layout is shown?

Answer (score 0):

two options for you.

1. assert on the next activity component to see it is correctly showing. or,
2. You probably need to test the Intent that you are sending through button clicks.

see https://google.github.io/android-testing-support-library/docs/espresso/intents/

```
    @Test
    public void validateIntentSentToPackage() {
        user.clickOnView(system.getView(R.id.callButton));
        intended(toPackage("com.android.phone"));
    }
```